# How to set an ACTIVE CSS Class using PHP based on the page you are viewing?

Tags: php

Below is a very basic example of a very un-elegant way of setting an **"active"** CSS Class on a menu item based on the page you are viewing with PHP...

```
if($this->currentPageName) === 'lead_records'){
    $leadRecordsActiveMenu = ' nav-tab-active';
    $followUpLeadsActiveMenu = '';
    $massAddLeadRecordsActiveMenu = '';
    $leadRecordSettingsActiveMenu = '';
}
if($this->currentPageName) === 'follow_up_lead_records'{
    ' nav-tab-active';
    $leadRecordsActiveMenu = '';
    $followUpLeadsActiveMenu = ' nav-tab-active';
    $massAddLeadRecordsActiveMenu = '';
    $leadRecordSettingsActiveMenu = '';
}
if($this->currentPageName) === 'mass_add_lead_records'){
    $leadRecordsActiveMenu = '';
    $followUpLeadsActiveMenu = '';
    $massAddLeadRecordsActiveMenu = ' nav-tab-active';
    $leadRecordSettingsActiveMenu = '';
}
if($this->currentPageName) === 'lead_record_settings'){
    $leadRecordsActiveMenu = '';
    $followUpLeadsActiveMenu = '';
    $massAddLeadRecordsActiveMenu = '';
    $leadRecordSettingsActiveMenu = ' nav-tab-active';
}

echo '<h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
    <a class="nav-tab'.$leadRecordsActiveMenu.'" href="/admin.php?page=lead_records">Leads</a>
    <a class="nav-tab'.$followUpLeadsActiveMenu.'" href="/admin.php?page=follow_up_lead_records">Follow Up Leads</a>
    <a class="nav-tab'.$massAddLeadRecordsActiveMenu.'" href="/admin.php?page=mass_add_lead_records">Mass Add Leads</a>
    <a class="nav-tab'.$leadRecordSettingsActiveMenu.'" href="/admin.php?page=lead_record_settings">Lead Settings</a>
</h2>';
```

So this is sort of a dummy project that doesn't even exist for me right now but it is one of these things that comes up across many projects.  Now granted when I am working with something like WordPress or Laravel, then there is generally all sorts of more elegant solutions available.  This is more for those small projects that are only PHP without any type of framework or library to utilize.

The idea is many projects will have a menu where you will need to set a simple CSS class to show which item in the menu is **Active**,

So based on this simple 4 menu items menu, how would you go able setting the CSS Class `nav-tab-active` in the HTML output generated based on which page you are viewing.  The source of the page would be contained in this PHP variable `$this->currentPageName`

Would love your help and ideas on a more elegant solution for future projects on this pretty common situation?  As you can see this is a lot of sloppy code for a 4 item menu.  Imagine 50 menu items...

Comment: you... just set it? `class="<?php if($pagetogenerate == $curpage) { echo "active "; }?> nav-tab ...">`? Your description suggests you already know which page a user is on, so just check whether the page you're generating is the one they're on?

Answer (score 3):

I would simplify this code like this:

```
$pages = array
(
    'lead_records',
    'follow_up_lead_records',
    'mass_add_lead_records',
    'lead_record_settings'
);


echo '<h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">';

    foreach ($pages as $page) 
    {
        echo '<a class="nav-tab'
            . ($this->currentPageName == $page ? 'nav-tab-active' : '')
            . '" href="/admin.php?page='.$page.'">Leads</a>';
    }

echo '</h2>';
```

Sure `nav-tab-active` can be changed to `active` or having both classes `nav-tab-active active`. Anyway you'd better do it even more dynamic, you can put the code in some helper functions and call it whenever you need it...

```
class PageHtmlHelper
{
    ... 
    public static function DrawSimpleMenu($simpleMenu, $activePage = '')
    {
        $str = '<h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">';

            foreach ($simpleMenu as $page) 
            {
                $str .=
                    '<a class="nav-tab'
                    . ($activePage == $page ? 'nav-tab-active' : '')
                    . '" href="/admin.php?page='.$page.'">Leads</a>';
            }

        $str .= '</h2>';

        return $str;
    }
}
```

and call it:

```
echo PageHtmlHelper::DrawSimpleMenu($pages, $this->currentPageName);
```